# i try creat folder using php script as well in pvs server that system ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu-18.04, vps, web-development-server, mkdir

```
<?php
$type="student";
$paths="klm";
$a2="med";
$da="_";
$a23=$type.$da.$paths.$da.$a2;
$enpath=$type.'//'.$a23;
  

$folder_name=$enpath;
   if (!file_exists($output_dir . $folder_name))
            {
                @mkdir($output_dir . $folder_name, 0777,true); 
                echo "Folder Created";
            }
   

?>
```

xhello dev linux please fix my problem
im using script php in server vps trying to creat folders look like this screen but when i search about those folders i cant find it
the file.php in folder that this path: home/public/file.php
and also in this path there student folder : home/public/student
so i need to make child folder in student folder

Comment: You're suppressing any error generated by `mkdir()`. Remove the `@` operator and try again. You should see what's causing your problem.

Comment: ther is no error when i delete @ the code run but no folder created in the path what i need i run the code as page browser but when i use terminal its run and maked the folder $

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1053424/14853083) for information on how to get PHP to display errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit tricky but looks like `$output_dir` is undefined so is null due to PHP default behavior. So you're trying to create `student/student_klm_med` dir, not a `/home/public/student/student_klm_med` or whatever. Note that `mkdir()` requires an absolute system path to create a directory.

Comment: It's against SO guidelines to include contact info in answers, this can be considered as spam with the intent of gettng work.

Comment: run the code to ways first is as a page in browser run normall but no folder created the scend way from terminal its run and maked the folder i wanna first way ? did u get my problem?